# N Queens Problem - Number of Possible Placements

Tags: combinatorics

So, I have been looking into the famous back tracking problem called N Queens. The problem is essentially finding the number of possible ways you can place a n number of queens on a n x n chess board such that all of the queens are not in any other attack positions from other queens on the board.

I came across the following statement on Wikipedia: “The problem of finding all solutions to the 8-queens problem can be quite computationally expensive, as there are 4,426,165,368 possible arrangements of eight queens on an 8×8 board,[a] but only 92 solutions.”
The link for the article is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle

I was confused since it states there are **4,426,165,368** possible arrangements of the queens on a 8 by 8 board. According to my calculations the number of possible arrangements for n queens on a n x n board is equal to the following (the logic for the below equation is similar to the n choose k permutation formula):

[image]

So, in the 8x8 case the number of possible arrangements would be 64 * 63 * 62 * 61 * 60 * 59 * 58 * 57, which is equal to **178,462,987,637,760**.

What is the reason for the differences in our calculations?

Comment: (The en.wikipedia article may be taking just one representative between symmetrical configurations, see paragraph on [Constructing and counting solutions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle#Constructing_and_counting_solutions_when_n_=_8). Hm, no, never more than 8 in a group?!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4,426,165,368 is the number of ways to place 8 *identical* queens into 64 places, i.e the number of [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination). "Identical" means positions are considered equivalent if one queen is swapped to another queen.

Each combination corresponds to $8!$ positions if the queens are non-identical. Therefore,

$$
64!/(64-8)!/8! = 178462987637760/40320 = 4426165368
$$

Answer (score 0):

About the "computationally expensive": They calculated the number of ways to put eight queens onto 8 fields of an 8x8 chessboard, ignoring the identity of the queens.

But anybody in their right mind trying to place 8 queens in a way that they don't attack each other wouldn't try to place two queens into the same row, but would put one queen each into row 1, row 2, row 3, ..., row 8. So the number of reasonable positions is only $8^8$ or 16,777,216, about 264 times smaller.

But that number will be again much reduced if you don't try to place a queen into row three if the one in row two attacks the one in row 1, and don't try to place a queen into row four if the one in row three attacks the ones in row 1 or 2, and so on.

Comment: From your last paragraph, $8!=40320$ attempts (permutation of $8$ elements) are enough, yet $416$ times smaller.

Answer (score 0):

To compute the number of possible arrangements of the queens on a 8 by 8 board, you can compute the following:

Number of ways of placing 8 queens on the board / Number of ways of arriving at each unique configuration of the queens

i.e.

(64 × 63 × 62 × 61 × 60 × 59 × 58 × 57)/(8 × 7 × 6 × 5 × 4 × 3 × 2 × 1) = 4,426,165,368